# how to conwert a word to other word with javascript

Tags: javascript

i want convert example hi to hello in strang with javascript 
Suppose this is my body of post in web page

```
<html>
<body>
<p>hi</p>
</body>
</html>
```

how to convert "hi" to "hello" in page load

Comment: This question is far too basic. A simple Google search would resolve the issue. Zero research effort shown.

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName (could be dangerous) / document.getElementById (better to give an id to it)

Comment: I know search! I searched but could not find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the p element and then change the innerHTML

So your javascript code will look like this:

```
var pElement = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
pElement[0].innerHTML = "Hello";
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gr2x6s5s/)

Updated the fiddle as the user required:

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gr2x6s5s/2/)

Comment: thanks , but i want when page load auto convert this cod converted with Button